# Python 3-How to composite two pictures by using PIL?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm trying using genetic algorithm to generate a picture which consists of triangle pictures.I use Image.blend() function,but the result is too dark and looks so bad.How could I deal with it?

```
image_config = {
'mode': 'RGBA',
'size': sourceimg.size,
'color': 'black'
}




im = Image.new(**image_config)
for res in self.decode(chrom):
    im_tmp = Image.new(**image_config)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im_tmp, 'RGBA')
    draw.polygon(xy=[res[0], res[1], res[2]], fill=res[3])
    im = Image.blend(im, im_tmp, 0.5)
```

Comment: Check [THIS PAGE](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html) and make sure that both your images are of **same size** and **same RGBA mode**.

Comment: @JeruLuke This page no longer works

Comment: @MatiasAndina Thanks for letting me know. [Here is the updated link](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.composite)

Answer (score 0):

You need [composite()](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html?highlight=alpha_composite#PIL.Image.composite) or [alpha_composite()](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html?highlight=alpha_composite#PIL.Image.alpha_composite).